# Relative path image import from JSON doesn't load in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

**JSON file data fraction:**

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "category_slug": "food_supplements",
      "title": "Food Supplements",
      "image": "/../../public/images/foodSupplements.png",
    }
  ]
}
```

**Component data fraction that renders the image:**

```
{
  Data.categories.map((category, idx) => {
    return (
      <div key={idx} className="header-categories-container">
        <Image className="header-btn-image" src={category.image} alt="btn-img" width="64" height="64"></Image>
        <Link href={`/${category.route}`}>
          <button className="header-category-button">{category.title}</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    )
  })
}
```

The error that occurs in the console is the following:
The requested resource isn't a valid image for `/../../public/images/foodSupplements.png received text/html; charset=utf-8`

Tried putting images into different sources, still didn't work. Tried to import with src=require(...), still the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try**

```js
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "category_slug": "food_supplements",
      "title": "Food Supplements",
      "image": "/images/foodSupplements.png",
    }
  ]
}
```

**Analysis**
If you have `images` folder in the `public` folder then during runtime (in browser) you can fetch the assets from the public folder directly i.e. `/images/foodSupplements.png` = `public/images/foodSupplements.png`

Answer (score 3):

Add that file to `public` folder and change image path to this.

`"image": "/foodSupplements.png"`, should fix the issue